# DDEInitiate Command Not Responding in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dde

I have the following code in .xlsm file:

```
Sub OpenChannel()
    Dim Chan As Long
    Chan = DDEInitiate("WinWedge", "COM4") ' freezing here!!!!
    DDETerminate Chan
End Sub
```

When I run the code on my computer's current Account, the .xlsm file freezes because of the `DDEInitiate` command. Then, I created a brand new Account and ran the same .xlsm file in it, everything seems to work fine.

What is possibly corrupted in my original Account that is associated with DDE commands?

Comment: This is out of scope I think as it falls into the debugging category unless we can reproduce it as per the SO guidelines.

Comment: in starting close all DDE using `DDETerminate` and then Initiate a new one `DDEInitiate("WinWedge", "COM4")`. I think this might solve your problem.

Comment: Is there `DDETerminateAll` for Excel?

Comment: yes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/application-ddeterminateall-method-word close all channels and then initiate new DDE